# CV or CC battery charging via SMPS module

Tags: battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, ups

I am using attached SMPS module, it has battery back up UPS function. I read the datasheet and I couldn't find information what type of battery charge scheme I need to use.

1. Should I use constant voltage charge battery?
2. Should I use constant current charge battery?

[SMPS Datasheet](http://www.meanwell.com/mw_search/PSC-60/PSC-60-spec.pdf)

Comment: The SMPS Vout for a 12V battery = 13.8V, which is the typically recommended voltage for a 12V lead acid battery in 'float' use. So, connect the battery to the power supply output. They show a series charging resistor, which is "strange". | Important: They provide a "Bat Low" signal.  on pin 1 which is used to control a relay or similar to turn OFF the battery output when battery voltage is too low. Without this controlled turnoff the battery is likely to be damaged quite quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to care about the battery charge scheme, because charging is managed by the SMPS.

You just need to know the *type* of battery supported by this SMPS. It is not clearly indicated in the datasheet, but I'd bet for Sealed Lead-Acid batteries. They are 12V (as specified in the datasheet) and typically used for UPS systems.

Comment: I connected SEALED LEAD Batteries, its working, since on battery it was mention constant voltage charge. I assume SMPS is charging it via CV scheme. , how much time it will take to charge battery full and back time, I know some formula of constant current charge, will same will be applicable to constant voltage charge.

Comment: The charging time will depend on both the battery and the SMPS design. Their datasheets will certainly not give enough information to estimate it with a formula, so you'll need to make some tests to get it. But I guess it will be around 10-15 hours, depending on the size of the battery.